# Which one has preference in Ubuntu: graphic environment or command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I use Ubuntu frequently and I have seen strange things happening when using both the command line and the graphic environment simultaneously:

- For example, I can use right click on a folder (like "Downloads") and share it with other Windows systems. However, if I open a shell and edit the /etc/samba/smb.conf I can't see the folder I shared. Even if I use the "grep" command on smb.conf I can't see that. Does the graphic environment run a different instance of Samba? How can I check it?
- When changing the IP address by running "ifconfig ..." the desktop doesn't detect the new address. In fact, the graphic configurator can show a completely different address. Does the desktop use a different configuration mechanism? If so, where is it stored? can I edit it from the command line?

Comment: As a general advice, it is not a good idea to modify any configuration using two different ways/tools. Otherwise, you may have inconsistent results or have your modifications overwritten.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I thought there was only one configuration file (smb.conf). Then how does the desktop share folders?

Comment: what are you trying to do here? Are you using samba as a server or you using the clientsite commands? The difference between the desktop and the shell might be that the desktop is using network-manager. but i am not quiete sure.

Comment: I'm just trying to discover why Linux shares folders although they are not in smb.conf. It's just a matter of curiosity, are there two Samba server running? I tried to share a folder from the command line and I was astonished to see it didn't show in the smb.conf file. How can it happen? I checked UbuntuForums (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10316901) and it seems a user/program doesn't need to edit smb.conf to share files, but if so, where does the desktop stores the names of my shared folders?